# Rails 4 - Displaying values from different model in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model, Ownerships. Ownerships belongs_to another model called Team. Team has_many Ownerships. Ownerships is indexed off 'team_id' from the Team table in the db.

One of the columns in the Ownerships db table is 'team_id'. In the index view for ownerships, I want to be able to display the name of the team from the :name column in the Team table, based on the team_id. I've been hacking at it for hours with no success.

Ownerships controller:

```
class OwnershipsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @ownerships = Ownership.all
    @team = Team.all
  end
  def show
    @ownership = Ownership.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

The pertinent part of my index.html.erb view for ownerships:

```
<% @ownerships.each do |ownership| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= ownership.round %></td>
    <td><%= ownership.pick %></td>       
    <td><%= ownership.team.team_id { |a| a.name } %></td> 
    #want to display team name above
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If Ownership belongs_to :team, then use `<%= ownership.team.name %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
<td><%= ownership.team.name%></td>
```

as you already have association setup between ownership and team models.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have many ownerships in the view, invoke eager loading on the team association, and then reference the team name.

```
<% @ownerships.eager_load(:team).each do |ownership| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= ownership.round %></td>
    <td><%= ownership.pick %></td>
    <td><%= ownership.team.name %></td> 
   </tr>
   <% end %>
```

The eager loading will make the page more efficient by left joining from the ownership to the team, and no further queries will be required to get the team name for each ownership.

If it's possible for there to be an ownership without a team, use:

```
        <td><%= ownership.team.try(:name) %></td>
```

Comment: @SeattleDucati you're welcome -- remember that if you ever find yourself passing ids instead of objects then you're probably not doing things in the correct object-oriented manner that Ruby works best with. Params are an unfortunate exception, and they tend to make it look OK, but aside from browsers passing values in params, always pass objects.

Answer (score 1):

One of the columns in the Ownerships db table is 'team_id'.

In that case you can simply go:

`<% @ownerships.each do |ownership| %>
    <%= ownership.team.name %>
 <% end %>`

Comment: Since Ownership belongs_to Team, you can just use ownership.team to get the corresponding Team instance for the Organisation instance, and hence ownership.team.name to get the team's name.

Comment: Also correct, I wish I could mark more than one answer correct!